# How to allow a particular referrer page in servlet?

Tags: servlets, http-referer

I have a HTML page:

```
<form method="post" action="Servlet" name="frm">
    Enter your name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

A servlet will get value from that HTML page but I want to a servlet doesn’t accept from external page other than this HTML page. 
**If the request doesn’t come from the HTML page**, a warning message would be shown saying that the user are not allow to access the page this way. What should I do?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: so what should i say?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Comment: i have editted. please help me!

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to achieve this

**Way 1:**

Place the following code in the sevrlet

```
if(new URI(request.getHeader("referer")).getPath()=="static html url")
{ 
  //allow
}
else
{
  //redirect to some other page
}
```

**Way 2:**

1. When the users logs in for the first time generate a random token and keep it in a session variable
2. When you load this particular html page pass the session variable as query string
3. When you post the form to servlet post this value along with other values
4. Compare the values from session and the value received through post if both are equal allow else transfer the page to logout or some other page/

Comment: I try your WAY 1. 
I create two page: demo.html and demo1.jsp with same structure.
Then try each page to servlet, but seem it is not working. 
The result always go to p2.html
http://i1265.photobucket.com/albums/jj507/mabonblog/1_zpsfabe8c37.png

Comment: @kidsoul first print what you get for the following for the two pages new URI(request.getHeader("referer")).getPath() and hardcode what you get for the html page in the comparison

Comment: one more point if the referrer page is https then you won't get the referer information